# Blazor WebAssembly Publish to AWS Beanstalk

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, visual-studio-2019, webassembly

This question has been asked before, but no answers were given ([LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66099944/blazor-webassembly-in-aws-elastic-beanstalk-linux))

I received exactly the above-mentioned error. But will repost so others don't have to follow the link.

```
    Configuring application bundle for a Linux deployment
Writing Procfile for deployment bundle
Unknown error executing command: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Amazon.ElasticBeanstalk.Tools.EBUtilities.SetupPackageForLinux(IToolLogger logger, EBBaseCommand command, DeployEnvironmentProperties options, String publishLocation, String reverseProxy, Nullable`1 applicationPort)
   at Amazon.ElasticBeanstalk.Tools.Commands.DeployEnvironmentCommand.<PerformActionAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Amazon.Common.DotNetCli.Tools.Commands.BaseCommand`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
```

Any tips on this? I have tried publishing the WASM to a folder for LINUX x64 and then manually uploading it to the environment but they always end up with a NO DATA tag and the default sample project.

There is this [POST](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/aws/aws-toolkit-visual-studio/159/848308501) that states their project had some properties not set correctly, but from what I can see, there are no platform-specific properties settable in the WASM project properties to affect publishing in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I changed my approach a bit.

WASM (to my understanding) is meant to be a cross-platform platform solution. Instead of publishing to Beanstalk, I just published it manually for my desired OS (which was Linux x64) and spun up an EC2 instance.

I installed NGINX, created my domain routing in Route 53 and then proceeded to FTP the published files into the directory I prepared on the AWS instance.

This worked like a charm. You do lose some of the Beanstalk default perks such as ELB but you can always just set that up manually if your application needs it.